# why case class ask to override equals()?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, case-class

I have just started using Intellij on my PC. I created a basic sbt project and init I created a basic case class:

```
case class Category(cat: String, value: Seq[String])
```

this asks me to either declare 'Category' as abstract or implement 'equals(that:Any): Boolean' in 'scala.Equals'. I have used case classes before(not on my PC) and was never asked to do so. Why is it asking me this??

Comment: Please provide more code. If I use your case class as written, it compiles just fine. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/M2OoDVCcQsOx4OTjkr1skA

Comment: @ChristianNeverdal, there is no other code! I opened Intellij -> create new sbt project -> create scala class Category.scala -> write above code init..

Comment: is it the IDE or compiler that's asking you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206638075-error-case-classes-in-scala-doesn-t-need-implement-equal-method

It seems this is caused by outdated or experimental version of Scala/Java or a combination thereof.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue.